# How do you update the contact information of someone in CiviCRM?

Tags: contacts

According to CiviCRM API documentation, the .create() function with a specified contact ID should modify the records within CiviCRM; however, even after trying that, I still can't seem to properly push changes to CiviCRM.

In the code below, I'm trying to change Jane Doe's gender from "1" to "2", and when I change that by setting val.gender_id="2", it prints out the right result. However, when I try to "get" Jane Doe's information afterwards, it prints her gender_id as "1". So, it doesn't actually update the CiviCRM database.

Is there a way to fix this?

//TESTING FOR UPDATING CONTACT INFORMATION OF 'JANE DOE' in CIVICRM DATABASE

```
crmAPI.create('contact', {id:'12966'},
  function (result) {
      console.log(result); 
      val=result.values[0]; 
      val.gender_id='2'; 
      console.log('UPDATED CONTACT: '+ val.display_name + " " + val.gender_id + " " + val.country_id);

crmAPI.get('contact', {id:'12966'}, 
  function(result) {
    console.log(result); 
    for (var i in result.values) {
      val=result.values[i]; 
      console.log(val.display_name + " " + val.gender_id + " " + val.country_id); 
    }
  }
);
```

});

Comment: try crmAPI.create('contact', {id:'12966', gender_id:2}?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I figured out what went wrong. The gender_id change must be specified as a parameter in the .create() function. It shouldn't be changed in the callback.

The correct code is:

```
crmAPI.create('contact', {id:'12966', gender_id:'2'},
   function (result) {
       console.log(result); 
       val=result.values[0]; 
       console.log('UPDATED CONTACT: '+ val.display_name + " " + val.gender_id + " " + val.country_id);
});
```